# Phonegap image lagg

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a problem with phonegap and images. I am working on a phonegap application but for some reason the images are really laggy on the application. They are not like this on the website when i am in the chrome browser.

The website link http://www.morrigandev.com

```css
.overlay{
 pointer-events:none;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 z-index:9999;
}

.dark-overlay{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7)!important;
 opacity: 0.4;
}

.slider-image{ background-size:cover; background-position: center center;}

.slider-image-1{background-image:url(../images/pictures/3.jpg);}

.slider-style-1{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    z-index:9999;
}

.slider-style-1 p{
    text-align:center;
    width:70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:14px;
}

.slider-style-1 h2{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:800;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:51px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

.slider-style-1 h3{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.slider-button-1{
    width:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:500;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    transition:all 200ms ease;
}

.slider-button-1:hover{
    transform:scale(0.95, 0.95);  
    transition:all 200ms ease;
}

.button-green{   background-color:#27ae60; color:#FFFFFF;}
.button-green:hover{ background-color:#2ecc71;}
```

```html
    <div id="content" class="snap-content">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#" class="open-menu"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="open-more"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="full-bottom" data-snap-ignore="true">     
            <!-- Image Slider Style 1-->
            <div>
            <div class="overlay dark-overlay"></div>               
                <div class="slider-image slider-image-1">  
                    <div class="slider-style-1" style="height:270px; margin-top:-135px">
                        <h2>NEST PRO<br>LEAGUE</h2>
                        <h3>COUNTER STRIKE GLOBAL OFFENSIVE</h3>
                        <p>
                        </p>
                        <a href="#" class="slider-button-1 button-green">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a GIF on how the app looks with the lagg. http://i.imgur.com/VqACJXm.gif Those images are sliding around which it should not do :(

Comment: Your website have many element use css transition. But in mobile device, WebView (browser) is slow. Please try: Force Hardware Acceleration with translate3d. I think your website will be smooth. http://phonegap-tips.com/demos/force-hardware-acceleration-with-translate3d.html

Comment: Load your images from the phone (mobile device) NOT the web. You did not say which you did, so I am assuming the norm. Please read. *Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap* https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md -- Read #1, #4, #5